# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Tags: android

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

My code:

```
public class ViewMupuh extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static String position = null;

    private TextView textJudul, textLirik;
    private Button bUpdate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_mupuh);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        position = intent.getStringExtra("position");
        Log.d("value of position",position);
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
        Lirik lirik = db.getLirik(position);
        textJudul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.judul_details);
        textJudul.setText(lirik.getJudul());
        textLirik = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lirikdetails);
        textLirik.setText(lirik.getLirik());

        bUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bupdatedetails);
        bUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditLirik.class);
        intent.putExtra("position value", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `position = intent.getStringExtra("position");` returns `null` and `Log.d("value of position",position);` raises this exception.

Try changing

```
Log.d("value of position",position);
```

For

```
Log.d("value of position", "" + position); // If position is null will log "null"
```

Or

```
if (position != null) {
    Log.d("value of position", position);
}
```

Anyway, take into account that `position` can be null after `intent.getStringExtra("position");` in the rest of your code.

Comment: can me question more to you? i have problem again? @antonio

Comment: @Deas Maha Putra I'm in chat now, better talk there to avoid long conversations on comments

Comment: im new user stackoverflow, i dont know chat in here @antonio

Comment: we could discuss this more in chat  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77547/discussion-between-deas-maha-putra-and-antonio

Comment: i dont know how to create chat with room @antonio

Comment: @Deas Maha Putra Now you are in a room with me. I said "Hello"

Comment: yes i see, but i dont know how to replay your chat @antonio

Comment: stackoverflow said to me : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. @antonio

Comment: @Deas Maha Putra Oh, I see... I tried to grant you write privileges but I receive the same message "Users must have at least 20 reputation to talk". Can you post another question?

Comment: can me question to your email? because question in stackoverflow me can question after 90 minutes @antonio

Comment: this is my problem now

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deas.telkomuniversity.id.ac.macepat/com.example.deas.telkomuniversity.id.ac.macepat.mupuh.ViewMupuh}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0  

problem in 
Lirik lirik = db.getLirik(position);
@antonio

Comment: your offline @antonio?